# FactoryBot: Multi-Level associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

So im relatively new to factory bot, and im pulling in some modals on some older php code into rails. And I seem to be running into a problem with one specific factory creation.

Right now here is my basic `factories.rb` file:

FactoryBot.define do

```
factory :"Core/User" do
  username {"jDoe"}
end

factory :"Core/Sex" do
  title {"Unspecified"}
  abbreviation {"U"}
end

factory :"Core/Contact" do
  first_name {"John"}
  last_name {"Doe"}
  display_phone_mobile {false}
  internal {false}
  archive {false}
  "Core/Sex"
end

factory :"Core/Employee" do
  "Core/User"
  "Core/Contact"
  username {"jDoe"}
end
```

end

Pretty basic right now, as the schema is sort of a tangled mess. Anyways, for whatever reason everything works until I get to trying to create an "Employee" (Sidenote: I had to add `Core::` to everything and had to scour SO to find out how to add that to the symbols, since they are namespaced I guess? (I know that I need to use `Core::<Model>` to access the models in rails fwiw)

Anyways the models are relatively complex, but the important parts are here:

`Contact.rb`:

```
  class Core::Contact < Core::BaseModel
  self.primary_key = 'id'
  has_one :employee
  belongs_to :sex
```

`User.rb`:

```
  class Core::User <  Core::BaseModel
  extend Core::ActiveDirectory
  self.primary_key = 'id'

  has_one :employee
```

`Employee.rb`:

```
class Core::Employee < Core::BaseModel
  include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

  self.primary_key = 'id'

  belongs_to :contact
```

There are tons of other dependencies to tackle...but for whatever reason the associations don't seem to pull in the `contact_id` when making an employee. As in it specifically complains about `TinyTds::Error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'contact_id'`

Thing is, ALL the others work just fine. IE: if I make a Contact it pulls in the "Core/Sex" fine and I manually create the "Contact" factory and specifically pull in the ID like so:

```
@contact = create(:"Core/Contact")
puts @contact.attributes
@employee = create(:"Core/Employee", contact_id: @contact.id)
```

It works!, but I dont know why the other associations get pulled in just fine? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need that; You just refer to the factories as a one-word thing than then the Factory constructor has a `class:` option on it

just move all of your factories over to standard names

```
factory :employee, class: "Core::Employee" do
  user { create(:user) }
  contact { create (:contact) }
  username {"jDoe"}
end
```

when you refer to them as factories just use the short names with symbols and let the `class:` option do the rest.

Comment: Do I really need the "create" portion though? In the association? Or does it not auto-build or create I guess just be referring to it?

Comment: the create inside of the curly braces references the factory name. The association user references the association name as defined in Rails. There's nothing that correlates the two automagically as you suggest and that's a good thing, because you may easily one day want factories that have different names from the basic association names. it just happens to be in this example they are one and the same. As you go down with factories you make factories like admin_user and employee_contact, etc and so you are referring to the factory names you are defining there.